# How much throughput can Twisted reactor handle with websocket?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, websocket, twisted, daemon

I am designing a service that would open ~30-50 websocket connections getting financial tick data and writing it to MongoDB; it's possible that hundreds of messages will be received every second.  I am using Autobahn's Python Twisted Websocket for it, but I was wondering whether it is scalable on running one async thread.  My instinct is that both single threaded Twisted and MongoDB can handle that throughput, but I want to confirm that hypothesis.

I see 3 potential options:

1. Using 1 thread, connect to all websocket endpoints and call reactor.run().
2. Each websocket connection belongs to its own thread, which has its own reactor.run().  Run it as one main unix daemon that spawns all the threads.
3. Each websocket connection belong to its own thread, run in different scripts as unix daemons.

What would be the most robust option?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Option 3. is the only one that can take advantage of multiple cpu cores, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you describe your problem your application is IO bound not CPU bound. If you're going for an async solution you should try to avoid threads. It's not that Twisted doesn't support threads [it does](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/threading.html) but threads are just overhead when you're programming in an async way. Twisted and Autobahn can handle lots of IO before they start using up CPU. So as long as your application code isn't high cpu either you'll be fine.